# Routing Service v8 API question - more than a single waypoint/via?

Tags: here-api

I have a problem with Here Maps Routing API v8.

Altough the [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/dev_guide/topics/waypoint.html) states that:
`but a request may specify many more intermediate waypoints with via as well. See Route Via Intermediate Waypoint for examples.`

... I am at a loss how to create a request with one origin/destination and two or more waypoints. In v7 we had a single **waypoints** parameter which allowed unlimited waypoints.

In v8, I tried something like: &via=52,13;51,14&.. to send two via points, but that doesn't work.

The v8 documentation (which feel rushed/unfinished) doesn't help, and neither [their only example](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/dev_guide/topics/use-cases/via.html), which only illustrates the use of a single via waypoint.

Help please!!!
.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add as many times `via={lat},{lng}` as you have waypoints:

```sh
# Note: line breaks and spaces are for readability only (they need to be removed)

https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?
  origin=52.550464,13.384223
  &transportMode=car
  &destination=52.477545,13.447395
  &via=52.529791,13.401389
  &via=52.513079,13.424392
  &via=52.487581,13.425079
  &apikey={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you also know how to send multiple **via**s through JS API? I am refering to [this example](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.15.1/dev_guide/topics/routing.html).

Comment: You're welcome. For multiple `via` through the JS API, please see [this S.O. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62094618/3120193)